# App crashes after spitting out timeline on log

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm working on my app and am having problems with moving onto an activity to another. Here's my logcat:

```
11-14 21:28:01.304 13030-13030/com.bringit.bringitrecyclerviewtest I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.bringit.bringitrecyclerviewtest time:66780166
11-14 21:28:01.474 13030-13030/com.bringit.bringitrecyclerviewtest D/Activity: performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
11-14 21:28:01.474 13030-13030/com.bringit.bringitrecyclerviewtest D/Activity: performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
11-14 21:28:01.664 13030-13030/com.bringit.bringitrecyclerviewtest I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1db28caa time:66780525
11-14 21:28:01.984 13030-13030/com.bringit.bringitrecyclerviewtest V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{3534268b token=android.os.BinderProxy@1f24a11b {com.bringit.bringitrecyclerviewtest/com.bringit.bringitrecyclerviewtest.SplashAcitivity}} show : false
11-14 21:29:37.174 13030-13030/com.bringit.bringitrecyclerviewtest D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-14 21:29:37.324 13030-13030/com.bringit.bringitrecyclerviewtest I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.bringit.bringitrecyclerviewtest time:66876180
```

The first line of this excerpt of my logcat is when I enter one of my activities. The last line is when I leave this activity for another one upon the user's touch event.

I'm very frustrated with this bug since it doesn't straight out spit an error message to me so I don't know where the problems lies.

Thanks for the help in advance.

## EDIT

here's the code block for starting a new activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, DrinkMenuActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("cafe", cafes.get(position));
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("cafe_list", cafes);
startActivity(intent);
```

I've checked from my logs that the values that I am adding to my intent are indeed not null and have meaningful data. On the `onCreate` method of DrinkMenuActivity, I have tried to see if it ever comes through via Logging, but no Logs appeared on the logcat, which just means that DrinkMenuActivity is not being started at all.

Comment: @Heshan Sandeepa added my code thx!

Comment: try to change from `context` (which you did not show how you initialized) to `CurrentActivity.this`. also try to remove all data you send and check if the error persists.